# Is it normal for Redstone Ore to light up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I mine redstone ore, it always lights up. When I stop mining it, it stops lighting up. Is this supposed to happen or a bug with my game? If so, why does it do this?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it is very normal for redstone to light up while mining. I think it's to represent the fact that redstone transfers energy well.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! I have been very confused about this and thought it was a bug/glitch :D

Comment: It'll also light up when you step on it.

Comment: @Qwertyfizzle: If this answers your question, you should **accept** it by clicking the check mark near the left side of the answer.